# Wait until file is downloaded with react-js reactFileDownload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, async-await

For a **legacy project** I need to work with ***react-js*** and especially with the outdated ***reactFileDownload*** module.

Therefore, I am facing the problem of doing an API call to a server AFTER the user has downloaded a single file. 
For waiting on download I have seen

[How do i wait until a file is done downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110728/how-do-i-wait-until-a-file-is-done-downloading) (ObjectiveC)
and

[WebClient - wait until file has downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727928/webclient-wait-until-file-has-downloaded) C#

Since the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-download) on npm about *reactFileDownload* is - well - a 2 liner, maybe someone can give me a hint, how to do a

`await <reactFileDownload()>
.then(() => {proceed()})`

in node.js.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using express? Because if you manually handle the file download, you can use `res.sendFile()` to initiate the download, then use a socket.io message in the callback to notify the client.

Comment: Btw: add to the question what exactly you have tried (including relevant code) and describe specifically how it failed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the project does not use express, and I have tried to figure out, whether or not reactFileDownload itself offers some features that would allow a promise-based solution.

Fortunately, there is an answer from @ra89fi below, that seems to be exactly what I am looking for..

Comment: I doubt that's going to work. That promise is going to resolve immediately, and `// maybe wait code here` seems a bit weird, given that this "wait" is the crux of the entire question. I'm pretty sure there's no way to determine when a browser download has ended on the client-side; you can also [look at what the module does](https://github.com/kennethjiang/js-file-download/blob/master/file-download.js) and you'll find it's kind of underwhelming. Also, just to make sure this isn't an XY problem: *why* do you need to do this? Also, what *does* the app use as web framework? Just static serving?

Comment: I did a quick test with express, and `Sent: file` appears right away, not after the download has finished. However I found this: http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
var fileDownload = require('react-file-download');
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fileDownload(data, 'filename.csv');
  // wait 2 sec then resolve
  setTimeout(() => { resolve(true) }, 2000);
});
```

Then you can do -

```
await promise().then(result => console.log(result)).catch(err => console.log(err.message));
```

Comment: your answer looks really promising :) the source comment about waiting and then resolving implies that I have to add a delay after the fileDownload() call to mimik a proper execution order. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. I edited slightly to show how it could be done.

Comment: What if the download doesn't take 2 seconds...?

Comment: 2 sec was an example. can't know how long it's gonna take.

Comment: Exactly. Unless you find a way to track the download. This answer doesn't address the question I'm afraid.

Comment: My answer was targeted towards this - "maybe someone can give me a hint, how to do a

await <reactFileDownload()>
.then(() => {proceed()})

in node.js".